# Django Symmetric Many-to-Many In Both Tables

Tags: django, django-models

One thing I found frustrating in Django is the seemingly required asymmetry when defining many-to-many relationships.  I teach Django and would really like to find the "most elegant" way to describe and teach many-to-many relationships in Django.

One of my students used the technique of putting the class name in as a string in making her many-to-many model.  This allows her to avoid less-than-intuitive techniques like `related-name`.  This is my simplified version of her model - the *key* is that `Person` and `Course` are strings, not class names.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField('Course', through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='Membership')
```

But while this *looks* pretty to me, I am concerned that I have messed things up.  I have done some basic testing and see no downsides to this style of model definition, but I am concerned that I messed something up that I don't even understand.  So I submit this as a question, "What is wrong with this picture?"

Comment: Quoted models delay name resolution – nothing to do with `related_name` or how you access related models. For instance, your code will error on `course = models.ForeignKey(Course...`, as `Course` is not defined yet; `'Course'` would avoid that. While you can resolve that easily here by rearranging your classes, there are situations where circular references would make that more difficult.

Comment: You will find many illustrative [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) on the correct use of relationships in the documentation, including the rare cases where you need [intermediate models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#s-extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Thanks.   A key for me is that I am trying to teach students (a) to understand the SQL mechanics of many-to-many, (b) how to model data at the connection (i.e. like role), and (c) when to use many-to-many when doing data modeling.   But I am glad to know that I have not introduced any run-time performance problems using the string instead of the class.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing unusual or controversial about using strings to define a relationship field; this is fully documented. But it doesn't have anything to do with making the relationship symmetrical.

I'm not clear why your student has defined the relationship twice. That seems unnecessary, as does the use of an explicit through table. Your definition is exactly equivalent to this much simpler one:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField('Course', related_name='members')

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

Note there is no need to define anything on Course, and no need for an explicit through table - which, even if it has no extra fields, disables some functionality like inline admin forms. Given a Course object, you can do `my_course.members.all()` to get the members just as in your version.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what the documentation suggests to me as "the django way to do it" - but I think it is harder to understand for the beginning user.

Comment: Also I have lots of situations where something like "role" will be in the through table so I have to explicitly make the through model anyways.  And ironically, I find that even when there is no data modelled in the through table, I always need to add a Meta / `unique_together` clause - so sigh, I need to have an explicit through model then as well :)